# jBPM: Install process app with command line tools - how?

Tags: jbpm

I have jBPM v7 full installation on Wildfly 11, just standalone, no server groups.

I have .jar with the process app inside.

I can successfully deploy it via KIE Workbench - upload artifact, then deploy it on kie server and start it.

Now I want to do the same from linux console.

I tried jboss-cli - no luck. I can't find which node should I use do make the app running. The command "deploy" sounds promising, is completed without errors but the application doesn't appear on the kie server.

I tried to dig in the workbench rest API (in hope to use curl later) - no luck at all. I failed even to get any rest service called - 404 all the time.

So the question is - how to install the process application .jar on jBPM without using web UI of KIE Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

In a managed setup, you can use [controller REST API](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.11.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_controller_rest_api) to trigger the deployment/creation of the container for your application.

Also, you can use Maven to upload the KJAR into the artifact repository as detailed [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.2/html/development_guide/uploading_artifacts_to_maven_repository).

HTH!